# Make absolute positioned element expand to the left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show a list of elements outside of it's containing element.

It currently looks like this, which is fine if there was only one element (row 2). But when I have several elements they should move to the left instead of moving to the right.

[image]

The picture below is what I want:

[image]

The order isn't that important. What is important is that they should expand to the left, instead of expanding to the right. The numbers (1,2,3,4) should never be placed above the "table". There can be X number of "floating items", and I don't want to hard code it. Below is a snippet with all relevant HTML.

```css
ul.items.table-style > li {
    padding: 2px 5px 4px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    margin-top: 0;
}

ul.items.table-style {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
ul.items {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

ul.items.table-style > li ul.left-outside {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20px;
    background-color: blue;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.items.table-style > li ul.left-outside li {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    background-color:grey;
    color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3"> <!-- Added just to shrink the list in this example -->
    <ul class="items table-style">
    <li class="row">
      <ul class="left-outside">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 3</div>
    </li>
    <li class="row">  
      <ul class="left-outside">
        <li>1</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 3</div>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
      <ul class="left-outside">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 3</div>
    </li>
    <li class="row">  
      <ul class="left-outside">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 3</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add transform: translateX to your .left-outside classes

```
ul.items.table-style > li ul.left-outside {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20px;
    background-color: blue;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
ul.items.table-style > li ul.left-outside li {
   display:inline-block;
   width: 10px;
   background-color:grey;
   color:yellow;
   transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VilleKoo/mrtgjmdn/)

Comment: Thank you. Simple solution that doesn't require me to specify the width of the `ul`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `transform: translate()` instead of `margin`. he expects to offset the size of the self element.

```css
ul.items.table-style > li {
    padding: 2px 5px 4px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    margin-top: 0;
}

ul.items.table-style {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
ul.items {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

ul.items.table-style > li ul.left-outside {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    background-color: blue;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.items.table-style > li ul.left-outside li {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    background-color:grey;
    color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3"> <!-- Added just to shrink the list in this example -->
    <ul class="items table-style">
    <li class="row">
      <ul class="left-outside">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 3</div>
    </li>
    <li class="row">  
      <ul class="left-outside">
        <li>1</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 3</div>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
      <ul class="left-outside">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 3</div>
    </li>
    <li class="row">  
      <ul class="left-outside">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 3</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `right: 100%` to make right edge of container on the left of parent.

```css
ul.items.table-style > li {
    padding: 2px 5px 4px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    margin-top: 0;
}

ul.items.table-style {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
ul.items {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

ul.items.table-style > li ul.left-outside {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: blue;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: right;
}
ul.items.table-style > li ul.left-outside li {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:grey;
    color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1"> <!-- Added just to shrink the list in this example -->
    <ul class="items table-style">
    <li class="row">
      <ul class="left-outside">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 3</div>
    </li>
    <li class="row">  
      <ul class="left-outside">
        <li>1</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 3</div>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
      <ul class="left-outside">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 3</div>
    </li>
    <li class="row">  
      <ul class="left-outside">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">Col 3</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: This expands the container that contains the numbers as well. I want it to be "floating" outside the container.

Comment: I've changed answer. Look at that